# phonegap 3 barcodeScanner & undefined error

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to get barcodeScanner working on my phonegap iOS app.  It *appears* to have been installed correctly (i used plugman), but when i do the javascript call to barcodescanner as per their directions, I simply get "undefined" returned.  I can see that the js is loading properly-- if i console log scanner.scan, I get a dump of the function, but if I do something like this: scanner.scan(function(){alert("yay")}, function(){alert("boo")});  i simply receive back "undefined".

I feel like i am missing something really simple here... any help?

Comment: What variable is exactly undefined? Is it "scanner is undefined"?

Comment: the result of the scanner.scan function returns undefined

Answer (score 1):

Getting `undefined` is normal as the result is not returned from `scan` function, it's passed to `success` function as a parameter. You can test with the following snippet (from docs):

```
scanner.scan(
    function(result) {alert("we got a barcode: " + result.text)},
    function(error) {alert("scanning failed: " + error)}
);
```